# How can I modify each element of a list while iterating over it in Scala?

Tags: string, list, scala

I have a List of String declared like this:

```
var re1_emoticons=""::Nil
```

Which I have then filled in with emoticons (Strings). I am trying to add a `\\` at the beginning of each String in `re1_emoticons`, modifying the original var.

#### First attempt:

```
re1_emoticons.foreach(t=>"""\\""" + t)
```

#### Second attempt:

```
re1_emoticons.foreach(t=>re1_emoticons.indexOf(t)="""\\"""+ t)
```

#### Third attempt:

```
re1_emoticons.foreach(t=>re1_emoticons.indexOf(t):="""\\"""+ t)
```

However still don't find the way. Is there a correct way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `map`-function. It creates a new list with a function applied to each of the items. When you get the new list, you can assign it to the `var` you already have.

```
re1_emoticons = re1_emoticons.map(t => """\\""" + t)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with `foreach` is it does not return anything. Use `map` instead of `foreach` or use `for-comprehension` syntax.

```
re1_emoticons = for(emoticon <- re1_emoticons) yield ("""\\""" + emotican)
```